# How can I combine my customize module with Omnet++INET's simple module

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

As all the simple modules' behavior like 80211 mac layer has been defined in the INET module. If I want to add a customize layer between mac layer and network layer to handle network coding. How can I combine the customize module and INET's simple module ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add a new module between network layer and MAC layer I suggest creating a modified host in a new project. For `OMNeT++` 4.6 and `INET` 3.2.4 do the following:

1. Create a new `OMNeT++` empty project with src and simulation directories.
2. In the new project open `Properties` | `Project References` and select `inet`.
3. Right click on `src` and select `New` | `Simple module`. Call it `DummyLayer.ned`.
4. Open `DummyLayer.ned` and add:

   ```
   @namespace(inet);
   import inet.linklayer.contract.INic;

   simple DummyLayer like INic {
   parameters:
       @display("i=block/buffer");
       // here you can add others parameter
   gates:
       input ifIn;
       output ifOut;
       input upperLayerIn;
       output upperLayerOut;
   }
   ```
5. Modify `DummyLayer.h` and `DummyLayer.cc` (this module just passes every message from up and down, as well as increments counters):

   ```
   // DummyLayer.h
   #include <omnetpp.h>
   namespace inet {
   class DummyLayer: public cSimpleModule {
   protected:
       virtual void initialize();
       virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
   private:
       int upNumber;
       int downNumber;
   };
   } //namespace

   //----------------------------------------------
   // DummyLayer.cc
   #include "DummyLayer.h"
   namespace inet {
   Define_Module(DummyLayer);

   void DummyLayer::initialize() {
      upNumber = 0;
      downNumber = 0;
   }

   void DummyLayer::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
     if (msg->arrivedOn("upperLayerIn")) {
         send(msg, "ifOut");
         downNumber++;
     } else if (msg->arrivedOn("ifIn")) {
         send(msg, "upperLayerOut");
         upNumber++;
     } else {
         error("Incorrect gate");
     }
     char buf[128];
     sprintf(buf, "up: %d, down: %d", upNumber, downNumber);
     getDisplayString().setTagArg("t", 0, buf);
     }
   } //namespace
   ```
6. Create a new compound module for own host, call it `WirelessHostEx.ned`:

   ```
   import inet.common.lifecycle.NodeStatus;
   import inet.linklayer.contract.IWiredNic;
   import inet.linklayer.contract.IWirelessNic;
   import inet.linklayer.loopback.LoopbackInterface;
   import inet.mobility.contract.IMobility;
   import inet.networklayer.contract.IRoutingTable;
   import inet.networklayer.common.InterfaceTable;
   import inet.networklayer.contract.INetworkLayer;
   import inet.power.contract.IEnergyStorage;
   import inet.power.contract.IEnergyGenerator;
   import inet.applications.contract.IPingApp;
   import inet.applications.contract.ISCTPApp;
   import inet.applications.contract.ITCPApp;
   import inet.applications.contract.IUDPApp;
   import inet.transportlayer.contract.ISCTP;
   import inet.transportlayer.contract.ITCP;
   import inet.transportlayer.contract.IUDP;
   import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;

   module WirelessHostEx like INetworkNode
   {
       parameters:
           @networkNode;
           @display("i=device/wifilaptop");
           @labels(wireless-node);
           bool hasStatus = default(false);
           int numExtInterfaces = default(0);
           int numRadios = 1;
           int numTunInterfaces = default(0);
           string mobilityType = default(numRadios > 0 ? "StationaryMobility" : "");
           string networkLayerType = default("IPv4NetworkLayer");
           string routingTableType = default("IPv4RoutingTable");
           bool forwarding = default(true);
           bool multicastForwarding = default(false);
           string energyStorageType = default("");
           string energyGeneratorType = default("");
           routingTable.forwarding = forwarding;
           routingTable.multicastForwarding = multicastForwarding;  
           *.interfaceTableModule = default(absPath(".interfaceTable"));
           *.routingTableModule = default(routingTableType != "" ? absPath(".routingTable") : "");
           *.energySourceModule = default(energyStorageType != "" ? absPath(".energyStorage") : "");
           *.mobilityModule = default(mobilityType != "" ? absPath(".mobility") : "");
           int numTcpApps = default(0);
           int numUdpApps = default(0); 
           int numPingApps = default(0); 
           bool hasTcp = default(numTcpApps > 0);
           bool hasUdp = default(numUdpApps > 0);
           string tcpType = default(firstAvailableOrEmpty("TCP", "TCP_lwIP", "TCP_NSC"));  // tcp implementation (e.g. ~TCP, ~TCP_lwIP, ~TCP_NSC) or ~TCPSpoof
           string udpType = default(firstAvailableOrEmpty("UDP"));
           forwarding = default(false);  // disable routing by default
           networkLayer.proxyARP = default(false);
       gates:
           input radioIn[numRadios] @directIn;
           inout pppg[] @labels(PPPFrame-conn);
           inout ethg[] @labels(EtherFrame-conn);
       submodules:
           status: NodeStatus if hasStatus {
               @display("p=50,50");
           }
           energyStorage: <energyStorageType> like IEnergyStorage if energyStorageType != "" {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=50,100;i=block/plug;is=s");
           }
           energyGenerator: <energyGeneratorType> like IEnergyGenerator if energyGeneratorType != "" {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=50,150;i=block/plug;is=s");
           }
           mobility: <mobilityType> like IMobility if mobilityType != "" {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=53,200");
           }
           networkLayer: <networkLayerType> like INetworkLayer {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=329,287;q=queue");
           }
           routingTable: <routingTableType> like IRoutingTable if routingTableType != "" {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=53,250;is=s");
           }
           interfaceTable: InterfaceTable {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=53,300;is=s");
           }
           lo0: LoopbackInterface {
               @display("p=78,406");
           }
           wlan[numRadios]: <default("Ieee80211Nic")> like IWirelessNic {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=216,406,row,60;q=queue");
           }
           eth[sizeof(ethg)]: <default("EthernetInterface")> like IWiredNic {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=368,406,row,60;q=txQueue");
           }
           ppp[sizeof(pppg)]: <default("PPPInterface")> like IWiredNic {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=558,406,row,60;q=txQueue");
           }
           tcpApp[numTcpApps]: <> like ITCPApp {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=147,54,row,60");
           }
           tcp: <tcpType> like ITCP if hasTcp {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=147,141");
           }
           udpApp[numUdpApps]: <> like IUDPApp {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=329,54,row,60");
           }
           udp: <udpType> like IUDP if hasUdp {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=329,141");
           }
           pingApp[numPingApps]: <default("PingApp")> like IPingApp {
               parameters:
                   @display("p=635,141,row,60");
           }
           dummy: DummyLayer {
               @display("p=273,350");
           }
       connections allowunconnected:
           radioIn[0] --> { @display("m=s"); } --> wlan[0].radioIn;
           // the order of connections is important here
           wlan[0].upperLayerOut --> dummy.ifIn;
           dummy.upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.ifIn++;
           wlan[0].upperLayerIn <-- dummy.ifOut;
           dummy.upperLayerIn <-- networkLayer.ifOut++;
           networkLayer.ifOut++ --> lo0.upperLayerIn;
           lo0.upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.ifIn++;
           for i=0..sizeof(ethg)-1 {
               ethg[i] <--> { @display("m=s"); } <--> eth[i].phys;
               eth[i].upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.ifIn++;
               eth[i].upperLayerIn <-- networkLayer.ifOut++;
           }
           for i=0..sizeof(pppg)-1 {
               pppg[i] <--> { @display("m=s"); } <--> ppp[i].phys;
               ppp[i].upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.ifIn++;
               ppp[i].upperLayerIn <-- networkLayer.ifOut++;
           }
           for i=0..numTcpApps-1 {
               tcpApp[i].tcpOut --> tcp.appIn++;
               tcpApp[i].tcpIn <-- tcp.appOut++;
           }
           tcp.ipOut --> networkLayer.transportIn++ if hasTcp;
           tcp.ipIn <-- networkLayer.transportOut++ if hasTcp;
           for i=0..numUdpApps-1 {
               udpApp[i].udpOut --> udp.appIn++;
               udpApp[i].udpIn <-- udp.appOut++;
           }
           udp.ipOut --> networkLayer.transportIn++ if hasUdp;
           udp.ipIn <-- networkLayer.transportOut++ if hasUdp;
           for i=0..numPingApps-1 {
               networkLayer.pingOut++ --> pingApp[i].pingIn;
               networkLayer.pingIn++ <-- pingApp[i].pingOut;
           }
   }
   ```

An own host module is necessary because `StandardHost` from `INET` creates connection between MAC and network layer automatically and it is not possible to add own module between these layers.

7. Create a network (for test):

   ```
   import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
   import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
   import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;

   network WirelessNetwork {
       submodules:
           configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
               @display("p=33,81");
           }
           radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
               @display("p=33,30");
           }
           node0: WirelessHostEx {
               @display("p=128,121");
           }
           node1: WirelessHostEx {
               @display("p=384,115");
           }
           ap: AccessPoint {
               @display("p=273,54");
           }
   }
   ```
8. Modify `omnetpp.ini`:

   ```
   [General]
   network = WirelessNetwork

   // node0 will send ping to node1
   **.node0.numPingApps = 1
   **.node0.pingApp[0].destAddr = "node1" // using IP address here is allowed too
   ```

After starting the simulation one can see that in each host `dummyLayer` send messages forward.

Comment: Thank you very much Jerzy. It helps me a lot. I have some questions after reading the codes. Because I am not familiar with NED's language so can you explain the code like `wlan[numRadios]: <default("Ieee80211Nic")> like IWirelessNic`. What is the meaning of <default("Ieee80211Nic")> and like. Is there any language like NED's language ?  And in the DummyLayer.cc, what's the meaning of `getDisplayString().setTagArg("t", 0, buf);` ?

Comment: The line `wlan[numRadios]: <default("Ieee80211Nic")> like IWirelessNic` means: create `numRadios` instances of wlan modules, each one of `Ieee80211Nic` NED type unless in `omnetpp.ini` is selected another type. To select another type of `wlan` module one should write in `omnetpp.ini` for example: `**.wlan[*].typename = "IdealWirelessNic"` where `IdealWirelessNic` is the name of compound module which has to inherit from `IWirelessNic`. The `typename` word is part of NED grammar, see in the OMNeT++ Manual.

Comment: The line `getDisplayString().setTagArg("t", 0, buf);` just adds a text from `buf` above icon of the module. Display Strings are described in details in chapter 8.1 of OMNeT++ Manual. Generally speaking, display strings allow adding any text to icon of module, as well as changing colour, position, adding a tooltip etc.

Comment: So the code `<default("Ieee80211Nic")> like IWirelessNic` means the Ieee80211Nic  inherit from `IWirelessNic` ?  As you say the line`getDisplayString().setTagArg("t", 0, buf);` adds a text form `buf` above  icon of the module, but where can I see it ?

Comment: Yes. The part `like IWirelessNic` means that a NED module selected for wlan **has to** inherit from `IWirelessNic`. So `Ieee80211Nic` has to inherit from `IWirelessNic` as well as any other module selected in `omnetpp.ini` has to inherit from `IWirelessNic`. In order to see a text above dummy layer module you should start simulation in graphical mode (usually it is default), then double click on a host. You will see internal structure of the host including the dummy layer module. Then start a simulation.

Comment: Hi, Jerzy. When I look inside the host and start a simulation, I found that the transmission is only based on the mac layer but don't go through the dummy layer. What is the protocol used in this model ?

Comment: I have prepared a general model of host, which is the same as `StandardHost` except an additional dummy module between MAC and NET. By default it uses IPv4 protocol and it is ready to use any of `OMNeT++` application for UDP or TCP. One can add this application manipulating `omnetpp.ini` only (look at examples in inet). I have only added ping application in `omnetpp.ini`from my answer. The ping is send in 1 s interval, so start the simulation and wait until e.g. t=3s, then stop the simulation and look inside a host. You will see that some packet were passed by dummy layer.

Comment: Hi, Jerzy, thank you for your detailed answer. I have some new questons now. When I start the simulation, there are some messages like Beacon, ProbeReq, ProbeResp, Auth, Auth-ok, Assoc, AssocResp-ok and arpREQ. What do these messages used for? Is these messages used for detecting the nodes around AP ? And when do the ping application, are the messages  broadcasting and must go through the access point and will ignore the messages from other point directly ?

Comment: How can i send messages between node 0 and node 1 ?

Comment: What type of message are you intend to send - a UDP packet or a TCP packet? Do you want send one packet or more?

Comment: I want to send the UDP packet and the coding node can multiply the native packets together like a1*packet1+a2*packet2. The coefficient are coming from the Galois field. And the the coding node can store the coded packets in the batch. I am confused that how to multiply the coefficient and data of packet together and add them together to form a new packet.

Comment: What do you mean by _multiply_ packets? Could you provide any example? Generally speaking sending a UDP or TCP packet using `WirelessHostEx` module will be the same as sending packets from `StandardHost` or `WirelessHost`. Therefore I suggest adding a new question and explain what exactly and when you want to send to another node and what another node should do with received packet.

Comment: Fine, I will add a new question and tell you the name when I finish it.

Comment: Hi, Jerzy,the question's name is How to build a network-coding based wireless sensor network in Omnet with INET.

Comment: Hi, Jerzy, I put the calculation in the question called The calculation in Galois field and this method can also solve the problem of overflow.